# Multi-threaded Network Folder access with JFileChooser

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jfilechooser

We have a problem that when a user selects the 'Network' Icon in the JFileChooser the dialog will appear to hang until it finishes collecting all of the 'stuff' on the network. Since the underlying class 'Win32ShellFolder2' is marked final does anyone know of a way to mimic the way windows populates the network folder? Windows will update the folder while it's still searching which gives the users a nice warm and fuzzy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- I have the read great idea by his majesty `VanGui_Ph`, in the firts (a few times updated) of versions I had the [same issue on WinXp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4450/6673), but never presented on Win7/2008,
- now is my post undeleted, later I have to delete that again
- I think that redirecting to the `Backgroun`d task (`SwingWorker`) solved this issue

Comment: Putting it as a background task will not help. The problem is the panel is not populated until ALL the network objects have been collected. I would like to update the panel with whatever was collected in that timeframe while it is still collecting more network objects.

Comment: See also [`FileBrowser `](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/6692) about `SwingWorker`.

Comment: then you have issue with wrong concept, JPanel coudl be popupated, visible on the screen, waiting notice should be visible, then to start Network, if done to hide waiting notice (I have 8-16 seconds estimated on WinXp, on Win7/2008 is about second, I think is cached by Native OS)